# Trouble getting config values within Phoenix controller and/or template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to get a value from a Phoenix config file in a controller.

```
# config.exs

use Mix.Config

config :app_name, AppName.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  debug_errors: false,
  root: Path.expand("..", __DIR__)
```

`Application.get_env(:app_name, :url)`, for example, seems to return nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Reading the doc, it seems that you can define these env variables inside the `application` function in the `mix.exs` file, not inside the config. http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.0/elixir/Application.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs for the `Mix.Config` module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.Config.html), there are two variants of `config`: `config/2` and `config/3`. You are using the `config/3` variant as you're passing **three arguments**:

- `:app_name`
- `AppName.Endpoint`
- a keyword list (`[url: ..., debug_errors: ...]`)

This means that you're configuring the `AppName.Endpoint` key in the environment of the `:app_name` application, and setting its value to the keyword list (remember `AppName.Endpoint` is just an atom, so it's fine to use it as a key). To retrieve the url, you would need to do something like:

```
Application.get_env(:app_name, AppName.Endpoint)[:url]
```

For the sake of completeness, `config/2` allows to set multiple key-value pairs in the env for an application. Its arguments are, in fact, the application name and a list of key-value pairs.

Comment: That was right on! Thanks for the thorough explanation.